# The concept of parity for members in a group

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering if the concept of an even number has a construction within group theory? Furthermore does it have any application or further abstraction?

For example; as we know that all even number are not the sum of two consecutive numbers, could we atleast define an even member in a cyclic group $<a>$ as all members $b$ in $<a>$ such that $b \neq (a^c)a^{c+1}$?

Comment: $a^c+a^{c+1}$? what is adition?

Comment: I'm confused by your notation -- are you writing your group operation multiplicatively or additively?

Comment: Then in a cyclic group of odd order, everybody is even.

Comment: I mean $(a^c)^{c+1}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas what about even order?

Comment: So $a^{2c+1}$??

Comment: If you really mean $(a^c)^{c+1}$ rather than $a^ca^{c+1}$ I take it back. But under the second I think more natural interpretation, for even order things work out fine.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yeah i ment the more natural intepretation. Sorry about the notation error. So this isn't a widely studied concept?

Comment: Parity arguments are everywhere, so I am sure something close to the idea has been exploited. But perhaps not studied systematically. Maybe preimages of $0$ under a homomorphism onto the two element group would also do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your desired application, for a given group $(G, +)$, you could define the set of even numbers $E$ to contain those elements $y \in G$ such that there exists an $x \in G$ such that $x+x = y$.  That might or might not be useful depending on the application.

Comment: It's not too uncommon to see mathematicians discuss the subgroup *generated* by those elements (though I don't think they regard either so much as an analog to "even numbers")

Comment: Your definition is not the same as mine, as it produces less even members in a cyclic group of odd order then mine does. But in a cyclic group of even order both definitions seem equivalent (perhaps i'm wrong). If that's true, the set of natural numbers with addition must have even order. I.e $aleph_0$ is even.

Comment: What do you reckon @André