# The cardinality of the integers is divisible by all prime numbers?

Tags: proof-verification, cardinals

In this question [Parity of members in a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417800/the-concept-of-parity-for-members-in-a-group) I defined *even members* of a group $G$ as all members $b \in G : b \neq a^ca^{c+1}$ where $a \in G$ and $c \in \mathbb{N}$ . This follows from the fact that all even numbers in the set of integers are those members that are not the sum of two consecutive numbers. Now comparing to an alternative definition of *even members* of a group; that is the even members of a group $G$ are all members $b \in G : b=a^{2c}$ where $a \in G$ and $c \in \mathbb{N}$.

Consider a cyclic group $<x>$. If the order of $x$ is odd, then the two definitions of even members produce different subsets of $<x>$ which are the even members. However if the order of $x$ is even, the definitions produce the same subsets of $<x>$ as the even members. So the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ must have an even order, $\aleph_0$ is even! Furthermore by similar arguments for *trisectable members* (divisible by $3 $ and the sum of three consecutive members), we can show that $\aleph_0$ is trisectable, and with further arguments that it is divisible by any prime number!

How true is this?

Comment: Do you know anything about cardinal arithmetic? It may help to actually write down what the definition of "divisible" is.

Comment: Well $\aleph_0$ must be an integer then!

Comment: $\aleph_0$ is certainly not an integer. It's a [cardinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number).

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what kind of divisibility you have in mind as you talk about divisibility in groups on the one hand and $\aleph_0$, which has no canonical group structure, on the other hand. Also, I seem to miss the argument behind  " However if the order of $x$ is even, the definitions produce the same subsets of $<x>$ as the even members. So the group $(\mathbb Z, +)$ must have an even order, $\aleph_0$ is even!"

Comment: @Najib Is there proof that $\aleph_0$ is not a natural number? Stefan even order refers to an even natural number, divisible by two.

Comment: Yes, there is a proof, and it is: "by definition", the same way that a bike is not a natural number.

Comment: Ahh, so it is assumed. Well how can it be even then? How can we say the amount of members of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\aleph_0$, and assume it is not a natural number, its not very rigorous.

Comment: No, it's not assumed, it's proven... When you define $\mathbb{N}$, and then when you define $\aleph_0$, you see directly that $\aleph_0$ is not a member of the set $\mathbb{N}$. Have you ever even looked at the definitions of these objects? Do you know what a cardinal number is? Your last sentence sounds like you should probably read about the basics of set theory.

Comment: @Brad I'm not confused about orders, but about what you mean by divisibility. Reading the other comments, it seems that you need to fix your understanding of some basics first. This isn't meant to be offensive by any means. We can talk about ordinal numbers and their divisibility with respect to ordinal multiplication, we can talk about groups and divisibility and we can talk about cardinals, but at all times do we have to be precise about what we refer to. In your question, you seem to identify cardinals with group structures having the same cardinality which caused my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing some invalid generalizations.

Things that are true regarding order of finite cyclic groups for example does not have to hold for an infinite cyclic group. That is for example the observation that your two definitions agree only for groups of even order is true when you have the standard definition of the order of a group, but when you extend that definition it doesn't follow that it is true.

Extending the concept of divisibility seem possible, you can still do the same claim that a cardinality is divisible by another if you could divide the set in that number of equally sized parts. But that definition breaks down when extending it to infinite sets since it will mean that $\aleph_0$ will be divisible by every positive integer and $\aleph_0$ itself. I'd guess that it's true for any $c\ge\aleph_0$ that it is divisible by all $d \le c$.

Comment: In your last sentence, if you talk about cardinals and say that a cardinal $d$ divides $c$ iff $d = \operatorname{card}(c \times e)$ for some cardinal $e$, then your claim holds true. Furthermore, we must have $c= d$ or $e=d$, so "cardinal divisibility" is trivial for infinite cardinals (assuming choice).

Comment: The definition of order of a group makes sense for any group no matter the cardinality because the order is just the cardinality of the underlying set. I think you are right, however, in the problem lying being the distinction finite groups and general groups. The OP has implicit finiteness assumptions initially, then drops them to talk about $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: @user45150 Thank's for noting that, I've updated the answer. There are other definitions that are extended though, but that regarding the order is not about extending the definition, but to generalize a statement true for finite orders to be about all orders.

Comment: @skyking Can it really be true for all $c \geq \aleph_0$ when noting the fact that $\mathfrak{c} =2^{\aleph_0}?$

Comment: @BradGraham That was my guess (it's true for $\aleph_0$ though). Do you have proof that it doesn't hold for $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: @Skyking. Actually I can show that all transfinite numbers are not divisible by anything finite by showing we can't multiply them by $1$, contradicting my group construction. Suppose $2^{\aleph_0}$ is divisible by a finite number $p$. Then $2^{\aleph_0}/p = (2^{\aleph_0} \times 1) /(p \times 1) = (2^{\aleph_0} \times (2^1 - 2^0)) /(p \times 1) = (2^{\aleph_0 + 1}  - 2^{\aleph_0 + 0}) /(p \times 1) = (2^{\aleph_0}  - 2^{\aleph_0 }) /(p \times 1) = 0$

Comment: @BradGraham Why do you think that the distributive law applies to (transfinite) cardinal numbers (in that way)? You're calculation is quite untrue since similar calculation would result in $\aleph_0 = 0$ (ie $\mathbb N = \emptyset$).

Comment: @skyking Then I don't know how to disprove that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is divisible by odd finite cardinals. Seem's an interesting result given it's form as a exponent of $2$.